# How to get Graph API access token server side to post to my own page?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-wall, facebook-access-token

I have my a job running server side and posting to my own facebook page but the token I get manually through the API graph explorer expires and my app fails.

All I need is a access token so I can post message to my own wall programatically with a job with a new token.

When generating  a new token the "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token" API  is asking me for a URI ( redirect_uri ) parameter but I do not have it as it will be a job that runs in the back ground.

How do accomplish this? What scope is set so I can manage page and post to my own wall programtically through a server side job? I am not posting as any other user but myself at all times.

I have tried with this but it is still asking me for uri.

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXXX&client_secret=XXXd&scope=publish_stream,manage_pages

Answer (score 0):

Redirect_uri is the link to your application.

You can read more on this page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/